# How to structure an AngularJS function that will be used over multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So far all of my AngularJS has been on one page, and within one controller. Now I need to build a way to dynamically tooltips across all 6 pages- 5 pages that currently have no controller, and 1 page that currently has "FoodCtrl". The function I am building will: read from a tooltips.json file, locate the correct tooltips for this page by id, and insert tooltip content into the DOM.

myApp is already initialised on all of these pages. It is a small, flat heirarchy, like so:

```
--> Profile
--> Information
--> Test (has controller FoodCtrl)
--> Payment
```

I am looking for advice on the correct Angular practise here. Should I extend "FoodCtrl" with the desired tooltip behaviour, and add a "FoodCtrl" controller to the other pages in the site? Or, should I create a unique "Tooltips" controller for all of the pages, and somehow integrate this on the page that already has "FoodCtrl"? Or, should I set up a generic Tooltip Factory/Service and reference this from "FoodCtrl" as well as new specific controllers on the other pages?

Comment: Do you know about directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanisms of getting info from external sources need to be extracted into separate Services and injected when needed.
Helpful links
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.injecting_controllers

Example of using Service

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('tooltips', function() {
  this.getTooptip = function(pageId) {
      ...
  };
});

function myController($scope, tooltips) {
  $scope.pageId = '<pageID>'
    $scope.tooltip = tooltips.getTooltip($scope.pageId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, having done all of my AngularJS until now on a page with a controller, I was confused as to whether directives would work on pages that had no controller declared. Answer: they sure do, as long as the ng-app is running there. So I added tooltip to the wrapping div of each page that needed tooltips, wrote a directive called tooltip to figure out which page was calling for tooltips, and used a service to load the data in.

HTML:

```
<div class="pagewrapper" tooltip data-title="unique-page-title">
```

JSON:

```
[{
    "extension": "unique-page-title",
    "contents": [
        {
            "head": "Tooltip heading one",
            "content": "information on section 1"
        },
        {
            "head": "Tooltip heading two",
            "content": "information on section 2"
        }
    ]
}]
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', []).service('tooltips', function ($http) {
        var requestPromise = $http.get('path/to/tooltips.json').then(function (d) {
            return d.data;
        });
        this.getTooltips = function () {
            return requestPromise;
        };
});

angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('tooltip', function (tooltips, $filter) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var elements = $('.forms .tooltip'),
                    list = [],
                    title = attr.title;

                //use the promisey service getTooltips to load the tooltips JSON
                tooltips.getTooltips().then(function (tips) {
                    //Do some things to identify the correct place to insert the tooltip content, and insert it.
                });
            }
        };
    });
```